# Vimeo iframe won't display video but will play its sound in Tizen TV Web App

Tags: angular, iframe, vimeo, tizen-web-app

We've encountered a strange problem regarding a Tizen TV web app built with Angular. Seems like the video associated to a Vimeo entity won't be shown, but its sound will be played.

The strange thing is that, when clicking the Vimeo logo included in the video's overlay, it will load vimeo's page directly into the web app, without opening a web browser. And it works properly in Vimeo.

Currently we use a normal iframe that works on any web browser:

```
<iframe allow="autoplay; fullscreen" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/[ID]"></iframe>
```

And yes, config.xml has the following tags:

```
<tizen:privilege name="tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```

Vimeo is set to allow embedding for a specific list of domains. When allowed to embed from wherever, it got the same behaviour.

We're testing it on a Samsung M7.

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing this, I've managed to fix it after a bunch of tries:

Instead of hardcoding the `src`, send a GET call to:

```
https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https%3A//vimeo.com/[ID]
```

The response should contain a `html` property with an iframe that has a `h` parameter attached to the src url.